Subcaption and size of subfigure are offset
I haven been trying to create a figure with two subfigures aligned next to each other. For the life of me I cannot find a solution. The right subfigure is slightly bigger, and its subcaption is slightly offset to the right. How can I make for subfigures equal?
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[a4paper, total={5.5in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}  % Adjusted width
    \centering
    \caption{Baseline}
    \resizebox{6cm}{6cm}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    ybar,
                    xlabel={Confidence},
                    ymax=800,
                    xmin=0.2,
                    grid=both,
                    legend cell align = right,
                    legend pos=north west,
                    grid style={dotted, gray},
                    enlarge x limits=0.1,
                    bar width=0.3cm, 
                    yticklabel pos = left,
                    ]
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=blue!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Baseline_P.csv};
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=red!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Baseline_S.csv};
                \legend{Pre-trained, Scratch}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{subfigure}
% Added horizontal space between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}  % Adjusted width
    \centering
    \caption{Reptile}
    \resizebox{6cm}{6cm}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                xlabel={Confidence},
                ymax=2100,
                xmin=0.2,
                xmax=1,
                grid=both,
                legend cell align = right,
                legend pos=north west,
                grid style={dotted, gray},
                enlarge x limits=0.1,
                bar width=0.3cm, 
                yticklabel pos = right,
                ]
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=blue!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Reptile_P.csv};
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=red!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Reptile_S.csv};
                \legend{Pre-trained, Scratch}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Confidence histograms depicting the distribution of classification
certainty.}
\label{confidence_BR}
\end{figure}



Welcome to TeX.SX!. Your code is not minimal (many unused packages) nor working: we lack the csv files! Please modify with a set of relevant coordinates exhibiting the problem.

The tikzpicure is centered about the bounding box.  Use \draw[red] (current boundingbox.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); just before the tikzpicture ends.  You can reset the bounding box to just the graph border, but lose the \resizebox.

Without the files, this crashes big time.  But this shows the original bounding box in red and the revised bounding box in blue.  Note that the parts not inside the blue box may overlap.
There are options to do this, but they only work for group plots.  See trim axis group left or trim axis group right,
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage[a4paper, total={5.5in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}  % Adjusted width
    \centering
    \caption{Baseline}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[name=border,
                    scale only axis, width=6cm, height=6cm,
                    ybar,
                    xlabel={Confidence},
                    ymax=800,
                    xmin=0.2,
                    grid=both,
                    legend cell align = right,
                    legend pos=north west,
                    grid style={dotted, gray},
                    enlarge x limits=0.1,
                    bar width=0.3cm, 
                    yticklabel pos = left,
                    ]
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=blue!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Baseline_P.csv};
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=red!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Baseline_S.csv};
                \legend{Pre-trained, Scratch}
            \end{axis}
            \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
            \coordinate (top) at (current bounding box.north);
            \coordinate (bottom) at (current bounding box.south);
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path (top) (bottom) (border.west) (border.east);
            \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
% Added horizontal space between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}  % Adjusted width
    \centering
    \caption{Reptile}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[name=border,
                scale only axis, width=6cm, height=6cm,
                ybar,
                xlabel={Confidence},
                ymax=2100,
                xmin=0.2,
                xmax=1,
                grid=both,
                legend cell align = right,
                legend pos=north west,
                grid style={dotted, gray},
                enlarge x limits=0.1,
                bar width=0.3cm, 
                yticklabel pos = right,
                ]
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=blue!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Reptile_P.csv};
                \addplot+ [opacity=0.5, fill=red!30, bar shift=-0.15cm] table [x=confidence, y=freq, col sep=comma] {CSVs/Confidence/Reptile_S.csv};
                \legend{Pre-trained, Scratch}
            \end{axis}
            \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
            \coordinate (top) at (current bounding box.north);
            \coordinate (bottom) at (current bounding box.south);
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path (top) (bottom) (border.west) (border.east);
            \draw[blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Confidence histograms depicting the distribution of classification
certainty.}
\label{confidence_BR}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

